# What's the convention for label prefixes?

Tags: cross-referencing, best-practices, cleveref, fancyref

[`fancyref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyref)'s documentation gives the prefixes

- `chap`, for chapters
- `sec`, for sections
- `eq`
- `fig`
- `tab`
- `enum`, for ``Enumeration''
- `fn`, for footnotes

The [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing) has some differences,

- `ch` instead of `chap`
- `itm` instead of `enum` (if my understanding is correct)

And adds

- `subsec`
- `lst`, for code listings
- `alg`, for algorithms
- `app`, for an appendix subsection

What are the modern convention for prefixes? I want to use `cleveref`.

What are `enum` and `itm` for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What are the modern conventions for prefixes? I want to use `cleveref`.

The good news is that `cleveref` imposes no stylistic conventions and only two absolute constraints on how the arguments of `\label` directives may be formed.

- The first constraint is that comma characters (`,`) *must not* be part of a `\label`.
- The second active (pun intended) constraint is that no "active" characters are allowed in the arguments of `\label`. To quote from the package's user guide: "Cleveref can't cope with active characters being present in cross-reference label names. For example, if French `babel` support is loaded, the commonly used `:` in label names will often fail, spewing the usual random selection of mysterious TEX errors that accompany such deep-seated errors. The solution is to avoid using active characters in label names."

That said, it cannot hurt -- and it usually helps -- to adopt a few stylistic conventions regarding the structure of the arguments of `\label`. E.g., you might choose to use the `eq` prefix for equations, `fig` prefix for figure environments, `tab` for table environments, etc. Of course, observing a few of these stylistic conventions is likely to be helpful whether or not you use the `cleveref` package.

Comment: "spewing the usual random selection of mysterious TEX errors that accompany such deep-seated errors." Oh, I like their self-irony. :)

Answer (score 11):

They are just conventions.

They keep you from inadvertently reusing labels: you can have equation `eq:pythagoras` in section `sec:pythagoras`.

`\usepackage{showlabels}` while writing helps you remember what you called things in another part of your manuscript.

`enum` is for enumerations, `itm` for items (probably) .

Use what works for you.

Comment: Do you prefer `showlabels` over `showkeys`?

Comment: @Kurzd Didn't know about `showkeys`. `showlabels` was the first thing I found for the job.

Comment: In the case of `fancyref`, they are not just (stylistic) conventions. The prefixes need to follow syntactic conventions, so that the package can determines which label prefixes to use while generating cross-reference call-outs via its `\fref` commands.

Comment: @Mico I didn't know that either, Thanks.